# .htaccess url rewrite with two variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i tried and tried with examples posted here, but i didn't manage to make my htaccess run properly.

Here's the situation:
i have links looking like this

`domain.com/sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=500`  (home page)
`domain.com/sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=505`  (players)
`domain.com/sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=510`  (coaches) ...

i would like to rename them to

`domain.com/sport/football/`

`domain.com/sport/football/players/`

`domain.com/sport/football/coaches/`

etc...
and for all non-designated page_id's to redirect to home page.

All help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sport/football/$ /sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=500 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sport/football/players/?$ /sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=505 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^sport/football/coaches/?$ /sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=510 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /sport/football/index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)page_id=500($|&)
RewriteRule ^ /sport/football/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /sport/football/index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)page_id=505($|&)
RewriteRule ^ /sport/football/players/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /sport/football/index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)page_id=510($|&)
RewriteRule ^ /sport/football/coaches/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank Jon, it is doing some rewriting, but not what i wanted.
I get 404 error when i enter new url for pages other than home and i get redirected to /sport/football/ when i try to reach home.
Please note, default page in directory is index.html, not index.php. Sorry, i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RewriteMap Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for that. You must define the mapping from names to ids

```
players 505
coaches 510
```

and tell Apache about the map

```
RewriteMap football txt:/path/to/footballmap.txt
```

The `RewriteMap` must be in either the main configuration file or inside a [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive.

Now you can use this map

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sport/football/(.*)/?$ /sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=${footballmap:$1|500} [L]
```

If there's no key found, the default `500` (homepage) will be used. If you have lots of mappings, you can also use a hashfile instead.

*Update:*

When you don't have access to the server or virtual host configuration file, you can only have a fixed `RewriteRule` "map"

```
RewriteRule ^sport/football/players/?$ /sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=505 [L]
RewriteRule ^sport/football/coaches/?$ /sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=510 [L]
# maybe other similar rules ...
# this is a catch everything else and must come last
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sport/football/ /sport/football/index.php?lang_id=1&page_id=500 [L]
```

Comment: Adding RewriteMap just gives me 500 error. I tried with full path and even with just file name, since i've put it in the same folder.

Comment: You're right, I just reread the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), and RewriteMap is allowed in the server config or virtual host directive only. I also fixed a second bug, the missing `RewriteCond`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, i don't have access to server config or virtual host config files.